# Construction of an unbounded series with a given finite Cesàro mean

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fix $\beta\in(0,1)$. I am seeking to construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with the following properties:

- $a_n\in\{0,1\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$;
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)=\beta$; and
- the sequence $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i-\beta n$ is unbounded.

That is, the order of convergence of the normalized Cesàro mean is *not* $O(n^{-1})$.

While I am working on this problem on my own simultaneously, any suggestions on how to make it as simple as it gets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just aim for $\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta n\approx\sqrt n$, i.e., define $a_n$ recursively as 
$$a_{n+1}:=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta n<\sqrt n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Note that for $n$ large enough (namely, when $n>\frac1{(1-\beta)^2}$), we will have $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta n-\sqrt n\right|<1$$
and hence $$\left|\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta \right|<\frac 1n+\frac 1{\sqrt n}$$
while $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta n\right|>\sqrt n-1$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. One remark: in reproducing your proof, I found it somewhat easier to replace $\sqrt{n}$ with $2(1-\beta)\sqrt{n}$. The key conclusions remain the same, but now the difference $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\beta n-2(1-\beta)\sqrt{n}\right|$$ remains below $1$ for _all_ $n\in\mathbb N$, not just for large ones, as can be shown by induction (and letting $a_1\equiv 1$). Therefore, one can save the hassle of having to check that the recursion eventually enters the “right” zone (and never leaves it again after that).